# i cant subtract the dictionary value?

Tags: python, dictionary, subtraction

how i can subtract the value of dictionary ,,
this is the code

```
from collections import Counter 


no_of_shoes = int(input('input number of shoes'))

d=[]
for i in range(no_of_shoes):
    stock = list(map(int,input("enter offerd size").split(" ")))
    d+=stock
s=Counter(d)
customer= int(input("enter the number of customers"))

total_money = 0
for i in range (0,customer):
    size, money = map(int ,input("enter the size with price").split(' '))
    if size in s.keys() :
                total_money+=money
                s[size]-=1

    else:
       print(" this size not exist")
    


print("the total mony we'v got is:" ,total_money)
```

here i want the shoes decrees -1 so that if customer want the same shoe again the massage will shown up  (this sizw not exist)

```
   total_money = 0
    for i in range (0,customer):
        size, money = map(int ,input("enter the size with price").split(' '))
        if size in s.keys() :
                    total_money+=money
                    s[size]-=1
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont need this:
`s=Counter(d)`

Just use your list `d` with shoe sizes instead. You can easily remove elements from the list by using `d.remove(size)`

EDIT: if you need the Counter solution, the IF condition needs to be fixed:

````
from collections import Counter 


no_of_shoes = int(input('input number of shoes'))

d=[]
for i in range(no_of_shoes):
    stock = list(map(int,input("enter offerd size").split(" ")))
    d+=stock
s=Counter(d)
customer= int(input("enter the number of customers"))

total_money = 0
for i in range (0,customer):
    size, money = map(int ,input("enter the size with price").split(' '))
    if s[size] > 0:
        total_money+=money
        s[size]-=1

    else:
       print(" this size not exist")
    


print("the total mony we'v got is:" ,total_money)```
````

Comment: then you don't need ```d```. Operate with your Counter object ```s```.

Instead of 
```d+=stock``` 
use 
```for item in stock:
       s[item]+=1
```

that way you're holding sizes and the amount of given size in your Counter object. Once you get this right, this part of the code should work:
```s[size]-=1```

Comment: counter for create dictionary by the shoe and how many we have like {1:2,2:3} shoe number 1 we have 2 from it so when i enter 1 and price many of it will decrees  from 2 to 1 ,, then the counter will change to {1:1,2:3}

Comment: actually i wrote s[size]-= its still not work

Comment: yeah, you need to use ```if s[size] > 0:``` in your IF condition for this to work. So if the shoe size is still in stock, you can sell it :)